# convert time into milliseconds and compare them

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I am having 3 times. time1=08: 30:00, time2=18: 00:00, time3=08: 09:24. all the times are converted into milliseconds. And how can I compare time1 is in between time2 and time3. help me dude.

Comment: Post the code where you have tried to solve this your self.

Comment: comparison is done with if ... and in your case two if which are AND'ed maybe you should consider rephrasing your question.

Comment: k how to convert the time into milliseconds

Comment: convert all stringDates to NSDate and then to NSTimeInterval. Then sort them you can easily find if your date lies in between or not. Other way can be finding by greater or lesser Date, refer to NSDate's APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assume all times is `NSDate`

```
NSDate *time1, *time2, *time3;

if (time3.timeIntervalSince1970 >= time1.timeIntervalSince1970 && time1.timeIntervalSince1970 <= time1.timeIntervalSince1970)
{
    NSLog(@"YES");
}
```

Comment: bro please tell me how to convert time into nsdate and then to milliseconds.

Comment: in short use data formater, for details see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5813679/1403732. Good luck dude